# Tkinter Button to creat entries

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button

I am trying to learn tkinter and got stuck with a little problem.
I have created a very simple window that has 2 messages on top "Activity:", "Time Spend:" and a Button "+" on the Bottom of the Window.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("274x520+868+240")
root.minsize(120, 1)
root.maxsize(3284, 1068)
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("Learning")
root.configure(background="black")


def new_entry():
    n = [n for n in range(30, 490, 30)]

    for i in n:
        e1 = Entry(root)
        e2 = Entry(root)
        e1.place(y=i, width=133)
        e2.place(x=141, y=i, width=137)

        print(e1, e2)
        return e1, e2


b1 = Button(root)
b1.place(y=499, width=276)
b1.configure(text="+")
b1.configure(command=new_entry)
b1.configure(background="darkgrey")

msg1 = Message(root)
msg1.place(width=133, height=29)
msg1.configure(text="Activity:")
msg1.configure(background="darkgrey")

msg2 = Message(root)
msg2.place(x=141, width=137, height=29)
msg2.configure(text="Time Spend:")
msg2.configure(background="darkgrey")

root.mainloop()
```

The Button is supposed to create 2 entrys next to each other, every time it is clicked, but if i click the button, it will create the entrys once, clicking it again wont create the entrys on the window, but just creates this in my terminal:

```
.!entry .!entry2
.!entry3 .!entry4
.!entry5 .!entry6
.!entry7 .!entry8
```

If I remove the **"return e1,e2"** statement, all entrys are created in terminal as well as in the window, with 1 click of the button, instead of being created 2 by 2 for every click of the button.

If I remove the **"print(e1,e2)"** statement, clicking the button will create the 2 entrys only once, and doesnt show anything in the terminal.

New entrys should be created with a little space in between, until the upper border of the Button is reached (in this case 32 Entrys, 16 rows).

Could someone also explain why **msg1** is displayed wrong (it is not centered and it is splitted in two lines), but **msg2** is fine, they have the same specs??

Answer (score 2):

Your code stops as soon as the `return` statement is reached, and thus your loop never goes further than the first iteration.

On the other hand, if you remove the `return` statement, there is nothing in place for stopping your loop so it keeps running until it has created all your widgets.

I took an approach using a generator to solve your issue, such that instead of having a function `new_entry()`, instead you have a function generating the entries, and another function placing the entries when the generator is called.

I also simplified your code a little at the widget generation, and changed a spelling error (spent instead of spend). I also replaced `from tkinter import *` with `import tkinter as tk`, to not pollute your namespace.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("274x520+868+240")
root.minsize(120, 1)
root.maxsize(3284, 1068)
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("Learning")
root.configure(background="black")


def entry_generator():
    for i in range(30, 490, 30):
        yield place_entry(i)


def place_entry(i):
    e1 = tk.Entry(root)
    e2 = tk.Entry(root)
    e1.place(y=i, width=133)
    e2.place(x=141, y=i, width=137)
    print(e1, e2)


ne = entry_generator()
b1 = tk.Button(root, command=lambda: next(ne), text='+', background='darkgrey')
b1.place(y=499, width=276)

msg1 = tk.Label(root, text='Activity:', background='darkgrey')
msg1.place(width=133, height=29)

msg2 = tk.Label(root, text='Time Spent:', background='darkgrey')
msg2.place(x=141, width=137, height=29)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i appreciate your help, im not familiar with the way you have coded it(created the widgets) but i will try to figure it out. Do you have any solution for the msg1 too? it still has the same issue even with your version.

Comment: @Aru You can use a `Label` instead of a `Message`, then it should work - I changed my solution just now to reflect that

Comment: hmm.. weird, but it works, thanks. It sais that the default is "centered" when a text is created in a Message()  but whatever.

Comment: @Aru I tried making my code a bit more explicit, so it is easier to understand. Basically what happens is that the function `entry_generator` is something called a generator object. A generator object has the property that everytime you call `next(ne)`, it will return the next element of the loop. So the first time you call `next(ne)` you have `i=30`. The next time `i=60` and so on.

Comment: @Aru I think it is because that due to the dimensions of your window, the `Message` widget determines there's not enough room for the full line, so it automatically makes a line split. If your window was bigger, then `Message` would work too. `Label` doesn't automatically make line splits, so there you don't have this issue :)

Comment: ahhh alright thanks. it was confusing because msg2 is longer but is centered and right ^^

Answer (score 1):

> ````py
> def new_entry():
>     n = [n for n in range(30, 490, 30)]
>
>     for i in n:
>         e1 = Entry(root)
>         e2 = Entry(root)
>         e1.place(y=i, width=133)
>         e2.place(x=141, y=i, width=137)
>
>         print(e1, e2)
>         return e1, e2 ```
> ````

The `return` is the problem. Look at following sample code:

```py
def iterate():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        return i
val = iterate()
print(val)
```

When you run this it will print:

```
0
0
```

Because, `return` makes the function stop immediately and return something.
If you really **had** to return every value, you could create a list, append the things to it, and return that list **after** the loop:

```py
def iterate():
    arr = []
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        arr.append(i)
    return arr
val = iterate()
print(val)
```

which will print:

```
0
1
2
...
10
[0, 1, 2, ... 10]
```

or use the `yield` keyword (it will return the value without making the loop stop):

````
```python
def iterate():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        yield i
val = iterate()
print(val)
print([i for i in val])
````

will print:

```
0
1
2
...
10
<generator object iterate at 0x7fb64e584f68> 
[0, 1, 2, 3 ... 10]
```

With `yield`, `val` will be a *generator object*, over which you must iterate again to get the values out of it.
But, as the return value isn't used anywhere in your code, you can just remove the `return e1, e2`.

Comment: Thanks, i was just about to research that "yield" thing

Answer (score 0):

Another method achieve might be to keep a count of the entry and multiply the count with the height of the `Entry` widget

Here is an example:

```
count = 0

def new_entry():
    global count
    e1 = Entry(root)
    e2 = Entry(root)

    count += 1
    y_pos = count*e1.winfo_reqheight()
    e1.place(x=0, y=y_pos*1.5, width=133) # change the multiplication factor to change the padding b/w entry
    e2.place(x=141, y=y_pos*1.5, width=137) # change the multiplication factor to change the padding b/w entry

    print(e1, e2)
```

Also note that it might be better to use grid layout for such programs.

Comment: is there a page that explains the differences, or helps me with this positioning of the widgets? the way i have coded the widgets, is the only way i have learned so far

Comment: @Aru [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-grid-method-in-tkinter/) take a look.